# MySQL C++ connector and Boost

Tags: mysql, boost, mysql-connector

The 8.0.23 release notes say:

> Previously, to build or run applications that use the legacy JDBC API,
> it was necessary to have Boost installed. Boost is no longer required
> for such applications. The API has not changed, so no code changes are
> required to build applications. However, in consequence of this
> change, the ABI version has increased from 7 to 9. To run
> applications, a version of Connector/C++ built with the same ABI must
> be installed

What does "the ABI version has increased from 7 to 9" mean? I can't see anything in the docs about an ABI or an ABI version. Does it just mean MySQL 7 through MySQL 9? If so, why is this in the 8.0.23 release notes?

Second, why does it say that you need Boost for apps that *run* the JDBC API? Can't I just link in a MySQL lib (`libmysqlcppconn7v5` for Ubuntu)? Surely I don't have to link in a Boost library as well?

This app can be built on a system with Boost installed, but Boost (or gcc/etc) won't be available on the target.

Answer (score 1):

Up untill 8.0.23 you would need boost headers to build your app that uses JDBC API.

On 8.0.23, that need was removed and, as such, exported classes have changed. So ABI have to be bumped. Due to how packages are named on debian distros, it clashed against connectorcpp8 (X Dev API) so we bumped from 7 to 9.

ABI has nothing to do with MySQL version. It is the binary version so, whenever things are added/removed to exported classes, ABI is bumped.